# How to hide/reveal a block when clicking on one button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function questionDisplay() {
  let qBtn = document.querySelector(".question");
  let qTextShow = document.createElement("div");
  qBtn.addEventListener("click", ifElse)

  function ifElse() {
    if(qBtn !== true) {
      qTextShow.className = "info_q";
      qTextShow.innerHTML = `text`
      qBtn.appendChild(qTextShow);
      qTextShow.style.display = "block"
    } else {
      qTextShow.style.display = "none"
    }
  }
}
questionDisplay()
```

The qBtn button opens a div with text, but does not hide this block when clicking on it, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way is to write your code in your HTML, rather than creating the element with `document.createElement()`, hiding it by default with CSS utility. class, then use `.classList.toggle()` to toggle that utility class. Like this:

```js
const some_el = document.getElementById('some_id');

document.getElementById('show_text').addEventListener('click', () => some_el.classList.toggle('hidden'));
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="some_id" class="hidden">
  Some text
</div>

<button id="show_text">Show text</button>
```

Comment: Thank's, everything is ok, but for some reason the class was not applied, const qText = document.getElementById('show_q');
document.getElementById('question').addEventListener('click', () => qText.classList.toggle('info_q'));

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do in the `if` is to check if the `div` you want to *appear/disappear* is **block** or **not**. One way to do this is to use the `getComputedStyle()` method, which returns the computed values of all CSS properties of an element.

```js
function questionDisplay() {
  let qBtn = document.querySelector(".question");
  let qTextShow = document.createElement("div");
  qBtn.addEventListener("click", ifElse)

  function ifElse() {
    let computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(qTextShow);
    let display = computedStyle.getPropertyValue("display");

    if(display === "none") {
      qTextShow.className = "info_q";
      qTextShow.innerHTML = `text`
      qBtn.appendChild(qTextShow);
      qTextShow.style.display = "block"
    } else {
      qTextShow.style.display = "none"
    }
  }
}
questionDisplay()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  display: none
}

#myDIV.mystyle {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: function showQuestion() {
  let element = document.getElementById("show_q");
  element.classList.toggle("info_q");
}       class info_q is not added, how to fix it?

Comment: Replace `mystyle` with info_q

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this piece of code where hiding and showing an element is done using css classes by the display property of a particular element.

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#element");
const button = document.querySelector(".btn");
button.addEventListener("click",() => {
  element.classList.toggle("hide");
})
```

```css
.hide{
  display : none;
 }
```

```html
<div id="element"> This is an element to hide or show </div>
<button class="btn"> Click Me </button>
```